# ActiveRecord- Cannot expire connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, activerecord, concurrency

I have the following multithreaded code:

```
pool.post do
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do
     process
  end
end
```

where `pool` is a ThreadPoolExecutor from the concurrent-ruby library.

When I execute the code, I get: `ActiveRecord::ActiveRecordError: Cannot expire connection, it is owned by a different thread:`.

I don't understand why this is happening since each thread gets it's own db connection.

When I remove the multithreaded portion i.e. the thread pool and run it sequentially, the error is not thrown.

EDIT 1:

Upon further research, I've found that there is a dead thread. I get the following:

```
#owner of connection

#<Thread:0x000000012026baa8 /Users/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.2.2/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:333 dead> 

# current thread

#<Thread:0x0000000104a2b110 run>
```

I don't know why the thread is dying or how to stop this from happening.

Any ideas why this might be or how to fix this?

Comment: Do you get the same issue if you just create the threads directly (with `Thread.new {}.join`)?

Comment: @smathy No I don't- my thinking is that `concurrent-ruby` does not properly check  the AR connection back into the connection pool.

Comment: I don't think c-r is even trying to handle anything to do with the AR pool, that's the job of your `with_connection` block, which seems to be working fine (ie. when using the threads directly). I'd be more inclined to think it's to do with the peculiarities of `ThreadPoolExecutor` and how/when that pool is being shut down.

Comment: @smathy Hmmm- yes it may be. The error is being raised from the active record expire method shown [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb#L339). In my code, the @owner is a dead thread wheres `Thread.current` is an active thread- since these are the different, an error is raised. I just wonder why the thread is dead and not checking the connection back into the pool.